# Is there a way to automatically resize a virtual machine display with VNC?

Tags: rhel, vnc, virt-manager

Every thread I can find asking about automatic screen resizing for a VM has a solution that involves using Spice. However, I'm using RHEL 9, which has disabled using Spice with virtual machines, with VNC being the only other option. Is there a way to get the guest to resize to the window in virt-manager using VNC?